# How do I manually change shortcut keybinding on MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For some reason my `control^` key shows the desktop every time I push it.  It's driving me nuts.  I've looked at the keyboards mappings in system pref >> keyboard and system pref >> mission control and cannot find the settings.

Can I remove this setting manually?

Comment: Which version of MacOS you use ?

Comment: @rootkonda Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: Don't you see "Show Desktop" option under "Shortcuts" tab of Keyboard ? If so, update this

Comment: @rootkonda Yes... I see that option, but it shows F11 as the key (which also works to show the desktop as it should).  Seems like there is a keybindings file somewhere that also has control^ bound to the desktop shortcut.

Comment: Check this out - https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-keybindings.html

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help since there is no way to bind a null setting to override an existing setting.. thanks for the help though